# Highlight current menu item lift

Tags: lift

How can I determine the page I am currently on in Lift?

In django, for example, in my base template I had simple checks like these:

```
<li {% ifequal main_navigation "home" %} class="selected"{%endifequal%}>
    <a href="{% url home %}">Home</a>
</li>
<li {% ifequal main_navigation "risk"%}class="selected"{%endifequal%}>
    <a href="{% url risk %}">Risk</a>
</li>

<li {% ifequal main_navigation "contact" %}class="selected"{%endifequal%}>
    <a href="{% url contact %}">Contact</a>
</li>
```

here, the *if* determines what the context variable **main_navigation** is set to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the sitemap for your menu.

When rendering the menu with the Menu.builder snippet you can use additional parameters to further tweak the menu. This example will render only the first level of the menu and adds class current to the menu item if it's the current page.

designer friendly example:

```
<div class="lift:Menu.builder?level=0;expand=false;li_item:class=current"></div>
```

or

```
<lift:Menu.builder  li_item:class="selected" level="0" expand="false" />
```

for more details see the lift wiki: http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/SiteMap

Comment: I think i simplified my example just a bit to much: I also use expand=false. I'll edit my anwser to add this. Then the top level menu will show all items in the sitemap that aren't hidden and not in a submenu. see https://github.com/lift/examples/blob/master/combo/example/src/main/scala/bootstrap/liftweb/Boot.scala for a good example of a sitemap with submenus

Comment: expand=false does not help, but that's ok I opened another question for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993350/how-to-highlight-parent-of-the-current-page

Answer (score 1):

If you use Lift's SiteMap and Menu functionality, I think this is taken care of automatically. You can read about it here: http://simply.liftweb.net/index-3.2.html#toc-Subsection-3.2

To answer your broader question, within a Snippet (not a template), you can use LiftRules.context, which returns an HTTPContext including a path attribute.