# How to highlight parent of the current page?

Tags: lift

How can I hightlight the parent menu item of the current page?

I have a site map as follows:

```
 val siteMap = SiteMap(
      Menu("Home") / "index",
      Menu("Search") / "search" submenus (
          Menu("Search Results") / "search-results") >> Hidden)
```

and I use it as follows:

```
<lift:Menu.builder ul:class="tabs" li_item:class="selected"  />
```

However, when I navigate to the **/search-results** - the **search** menu item is no longer selected (i.e. the css class *selected* is no longer applied to it).

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's quite simple. You should use Lift built-in snippet Menu parameter **li_path**

something from documentation:

> li_path - Adds the specified attribute
>   to the current page’s breadcrumb trail
>   (the breadcrumb trail is the set of
>   menu items that are direct ancestors
>   in the menu tree)

so in your code, you could do just:

```
<lift:Menu.builder ul:class="tabs" li_item:class="selected" li_path:class="selected" />
```

Hope this helps. If you could have any other questions just ask :)

Comment: Magic!!! It's like they thought of everything. I wander what would happen if something is not available. Does the whole thing just break down?

Comment: @drozzy What did you mean that the whole thing just break down? What would happen that something is not available? What?

Comment: What if "li_path" was no provided by lift. What would one do then? I mean with lift - am I really dependent on it's developers - or is it easy to add functionality by myself? Sorry for the confusing thought!

Comment: @drozzy oh yes, I understand. So you could write your own Menu snippet or you could select your parent elements in list with appropriate class using jquery selectors or you could kindly ask for this feature on Lift Google Group list and I'm sure that if there would be need, they add it in next version of Lift. I have these experiences.